# How to display a Modal form in a position relative to the a control in the parent window (opener)

Tags: c#, winforms

Well, I have a form that I open using:

```
ShowDialog(this);
```

I try to change the position of the form using its `Location` property, but I don't understand what exactly is this position relative to? I want to open this form below a certain button. So how can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Form will expect the co-ordinates relative to the screen’s top-left corner. However, the location of a Control *within* a Form is relative to the top-left corner of the form<sup>†</sup>.

Use the Control’s `Location` property to find its location, and then call `PointToScreen` on the Form object to turn it into screen co-ordinates. Then you can position the new form relative to that.

For example:

```
var locationInForm = myControl.Location;
var locationOnScreen = mainForm.PointToScreen(locationInForm);

using (var model = new ModelForm())
{
    model.Location = new Point(locationOnScreen.X, locationOnScreen.Y + myControl.Height + 3);
    model.ShowDialog();
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup> *Actually the top-left corner of the client area of the form.*

Comment: The code for setting the form's location is incorrect.  It should be: `model.Location = new Point(locationOnScreen.X, locationOnScreen.Y + myControl.Height + 3);`

Comment: as a note... modalForm.startingPosition have to be "manual" to take location into account

Answer (score 5):

I preferred this:

```
myModalForm.Location = New Point(myControl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X + myControl.Width, myControl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y)
```