# Open childform in upper right corner of mainform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open a (non decorated) childform at the upper right corner of my main form no matter if the main form is maximized or at it's normal size.
But no matter how I try I don't get it to open where I want it to.

I found a post that described how to open the form relative to another control in the form, but that didn't work either:

[How to display a Modal form in a position relative to the a control in the parent window (opener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540135/how-display-a-model-form-in-a-position-relative-to-the-a-control-in-the-parent-w)

Have tried to search for a few hours now on google for a solution, but either there's no answer (doubdfull) or I am not searching for the tight words combination (more likely).

Could anyone please either point me to a similar question, or help me how to achieve what I am hoping for?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me you ought to be using a UserControl that you anchor to the top and right.  But let's make a form work.  You'll need to wire its Load event so you can move it into the right spot after it rescaled itself.  Then you need the main form's LocationChanged and Resize events so you can keep the child form in the right spot.

So a sample program with boilerplate Form1 and Form2 names and a button on Form1 to display the child could look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Click += button1_Click;
        this.Resize += this.Form1_Resize;
        this.LocationChanged += this.Form1_LocationChanged;

    }

    Form child;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (child != null) return;
        child = new Form2();
        child.FormClosed += child_FormClosed;
        child.Load += child_Load;
        child.Show(this);
    }

    void child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        child.FormClosed -= child_FormClosed;
        child.Load -= child_Load;
        child = null;
    }

    void child_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        moveChild();
    }

    void moveChild() {
        child.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - child.Width, 0));
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (child != null) moveChild();
    }

    private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (child != null) moveChild();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildForm win = new ChildForm();
            int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;

            Point parentPoint = this.Location;

            int parentHeight = this.Height;
            int parentWidth = this.Width;

            int childHeight = win.Height;
            int childWidth = win.Width;

            int resultX = 0;
            int resultY = 0;

            if ((parentPoint.X + parentWidth + childWidth) > screenWidth)
            {
                resultY = parentPoint.Y;
                resultX = parentPoint.X - childWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                resultY = parentPoint.Y;
                resultX = parentPoint.X + parentWidth;
            }

            win.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;                   
            win.Location = new Point(resultX, resultY);  
            win.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    //"this" is the parent form
    frm2.DesktopLocation = new Point(this.DesktopLocation.X + this.Width - frm2.Width, this.DesktopLocation.Y);
}
```

Simple, easy, and works (for me).