# Popup window in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, popupwindow

How to popup a child form when I click the button. I want to child winform to be in the centre of the screen and the whole background screen should be blurred. and a small close button should be visible in the right corner of the form. I have searched the web but found nothing.

Using Winforms.

Comment: no. I only searched for the popup window and the blurred background.

Comment: You haven't told us if you use Winforms or WPF or what.

Comment: I can blurred the background by using opacity property. but still found nothing on how to popup the form. I am using Winforms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540135/how-to-display-a-modal-form-in-a-position-relative-to-the-a-control-in-the-paren

Answer (score 2):

Make a new windows form. it has a close button by default. Set it default position to center screen. Then on your button click.

Lets say your new form is Form2

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

it will not make the rest of screen blurred but user will not be able to do anything with it.

For blurry effect a workaround has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248748/c-sharp-dialog-form-with-blur-background)

Comment: Yeah I am doing this. But I want to make it look interactive. Just like we saw in web applications.

Comment: A non-interactive form would be a novelty :-)

Comment: Lol. But our teachers asked us to use creativity. This is why I am asking for this.

Comment: See my edit. i have posted the link. Though this is not a place to do homeworks

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger event from click button like this

```
Form form1=new Form();
form1.show;
```

and after that to blurr the parent screen use opacity property of and increase or decrease it accord to your requirement.
you can also control the transparency of the child form using a timer and increase paacity with timer click it will make it more dynamic and interactive.

Comment: to show it in center of screen use screen width/height and devide by 2 and set it to current position of form.

Comment: Thanks. But opacity only transparent the parent form but won't blur it. I want the whole screen to be blurred except my child form.

Comment: i think for that purpose you should use wpf

Comment: This is what exactly I am thinking.